# Ajax search json with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to get a search input field to display the corresponding tax from a json-form. But right now I'm clueless. Any ideas are appreciated. http://jsfiddle.net/9jFGG/

```
var jsonUrl = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/430406/Temp %5Bok to delete%5D/Various/salaryCalc/7100.json";

var inputValue = $('input[name=income]');

$('#input-form').keyup(function () {
 $.getJSON(jsonUrl, function (data) {
   $.each(data, function (key, val) {
    if (inputValue.val() === key) {
      $('#tax-calc').text(val);
    }
  });
 });
});
```

Comment: You've got some minor syntax errors that can be found by looking at your browser's JS console or using a tool like JSLint or JSHint.

Comment: if one of those answers fiots your nedd, please mark them as the solution

Comment: fixed typos. marked solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few typos

see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9jFGG/6/)

```
$('#input-form').keyup( function() {
    $.getJSON(jsonUrl, function ( data ) {
        $.each (data, function ( key, val ) {
            if (inputValue.val() == key) {
                $('#tax-calc').text(val.tax);
                $('#paid-calc').text(val.income - val.tax);
                return;
                }
            })
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You've missed a lot of braces.

I've changed your complete code and added a new function. This one now waits for 500 ms until it fires the JSON call. This is important because otherwise you would send the JSON request each time the user typed in a letter. This would be very bad on the performance side..

Also I've added a few comments for you ;)

```
//this one waits until the dom is loaded
$(function(){

var inputValue = $('input[name=income]');

//creates a new constructor function that handles the actual call and wait-time
var JSONSender = function(){
    //saves the timeout id to clear it if necessary
    var timeoutId = null,
        jsonUrl = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/430406/Temp %5Bok to delete%5D/Various/salaryCalc/7100.json";

    this.getJSON = function(_callback){
        //if a setTimeout is already in progress, cancel it
        if(timeoutId !== null){
             clearTimeout(timeoutId);
        }
        //fire the actual code after 500 ms
        timeoutId = setTimeout(function(){
            timeoutId = null;
            $.getJSON(jsonUrl, _callback);
        },500);
    }
};

   var jsonSender = new JSONSender();

    $('#input-form').keyup( function(e) {
    jsonSender.getJSON(function(data){
        $.each (data, function ( key, val ) {
            if (inputValue.val() == val.income){
                $('#tax-calc').text(val.tax);
                return;
            }
        });
        })
   });
});
```